# Android pushing new activity on top of TabActivity and coming back

Tags: java, android

I have a question that I've been looking for answer to for several days with no luck.

So, to be as specific, I have TabActivity inside TabActivity and listview inside it (I call this entire screen "main screen"). That listview is populated from data sent from my database. Upon clicking an item of the listview, I start an activity but upon exiting that activity and coming back to the main screen, the listview is recreated and I was wondering whether there was a way to stop from being recreated.

Which method do I need to override to simply start and finish activity without destroying the main screen?

Edit--

I don't have FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP attached to any of the activity

Comment: use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)

Comment: I have tried starting an activity using startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) but still the same behaviour is observed. Do the requestCode need to be specific value? Since I am not sending any data back to the main activity, do I even need to override the onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)?

Comment: post your code is helpful to find the solution